# Webpack + Cardano ASM serialization library

Tags: nami-wallet

I'm trying to use a library to access a cardano wallet, right now, I'm in webpack 5 and project run so far until I try to import the cardano library.
It breaks in the same point always:

```
runtime modules 33.6 KiB 17 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 17.5 MiB 49 modules
modules with errors 429 bytes [errors]
  optional modules 78 bytes [optional]
    node:process 39 bytes [optional] [built] [code generated] [1 error]
    node:stream/web 39 bytes [optional] [built] [code generated] [1 error]
  9 modules
./src/index.js 280 bytes [built] [code generated]

WARNING in ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-asmjs/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js 12128:14-53
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-asmjs/cardano_serialization_lib.js 2:0-50 2:0-50
 @ ./node_modules/nami-wallet-api/lib/index.js 635:98-148
 @ ./src/index.js 2:23-48

1 warning has detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

ERROR in node:fs
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

If any of you had success using this library and webpack please let me know.

```
{
  "name": "webpacktemplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nami-wallet-api": "^1.1.9",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.64.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: I would suggets to import it using a Loder like the Nami Wallet does it. That is the only way I could make it work. Also I would suggest to consider using the browser version.  Also I noticed that the error has to do with fs, i faced the same error but thats related to the way Next.Js Works... If you are using Next.Js .. try following the configuration i use in my project https://github.com/alice1989123/Metahagane . Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also come across this error in webpack, but found that it can be ignored if you use a Loader like so:

```
class Loader {
  async load() {
    if (this._wasm && this._wasm2) return;
    /**
     * @private
     */
    this._wasm = await import(
      '@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib'
    );
  }

  get Cardano() {
    return this._wasm;
  }
}

export default new Loader();
```

Then in your components, this should work:

```
import Loader from './loader'

/* ... other component code ... */

getAddress() {
      window.cardano.getChangeAddress().then((address) => { 
        Loader.load() // Note, loading the library here
        this.address = Loader.Cardano.Address.from_bytes( // Now Loader.Cardano resolves
            Buffer.from(address, "hex")
        ).to_bech32()
      })
}
```

As a side note, I've also found it easier to just call `Loader.load()` in my `beforeMount()` callback or similar depending on the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Use node-fetch 2.6.6 and it should work